# Not able to remove characters from the string using bean shell sampler

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Using bean shell sampler in jmeter how can i remove the characters before "$bbbb,P10,868324023031300,20160816090741" from  the below string
"=xxxxIoT2?data=$bbbb,P10,868324023031300,20160816090741"

Comment: You just want the value after $? So just use substring

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible options, you need to give us a little bit more details so we could come up with the best solution. In the meantime, here is the most straightforward way:

```
    String before = "=xxxxIoT2?data=$bbbb,P10,868324023031300,20160816090741";
    String after = before.split("data=")[1];
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell string split demo]

Also be aware that Beanshell is not the best scripting option so please consider switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as Groovy:

- is more Java-compliant (Beanshell is stuck on Java 1.5 language level)
- performs better (well-behaved Groovy scripts can be compiled into native Java code)
- has some [enhancements on top of Java SDK](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.4/html/groovy-jdk/) which make developers lives easier

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information.